# Unit test using sinon with promises

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, promise, sinon, sinon-chai

I have a function returning a `Promise` wrapped around another function that works with it's own implementation of the promises/callbacks, like so:

```
function getResult() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   const service = Service(config)
    return Service.initialize({scope: 'param'})
      .success((result) => {
        result ? resolve(service.res) : reject(new Error('Something happened'))
      })
      .error(() => {
        reject(new Error('Something happened'))
      )})
  })
}
```

**EDIT**: I can re-write the above function to something like:

```
function getResult(done) {
 const service = Service(config)
  Service.initialize({scope: 'param'})
   .success((result) => {
     result ? done(null, result) : done(new Error('Something happened'), null))
   })
   .error(() => {
     done(new Error('Something happened'), null)
   }
```

I don't know how can I unit test something like this? I tried to `stub` the `Service` and use `sinon` to check if it was called, but the following didn't work:

```
it('should initialize service and return res', () => {
    const mockService = sinon.stub(Service, 'initialize')
    mockService.withArgs({scope: 'param'}).returns(Promise.resolve(true))

    expect(mockService.callCount).to.equal(1)
  })
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is Service from another library or something you created? This seems like one or the other is redundant but I couldn't help without more context on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes, Service comes from another library we created and we use it as an NPM module. I know the Services' success/error functions look weird, but I don't have control on it. Do you believe this can be implemented in a better way?

Comment: You may not need to use promise here, however. If you show more of the code or let me know the library I can think of something.

Comment: Hi, you can consider the Service module to be similar to the keycloak-js library. The whole getResult() is an async function being called from a redux-saga.

Comment: @JoshMorel, do you have any pointers now? I've edited the question with a more node like callback approach. How can this be tested?

Comment: You aren't calling `getResult` in your test.

Comment: @NickShvelidze, I know the test block I wrote is useless. Actually I don't know how this should be tested. :) I know I need to call the actual method in there but that too doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You are just checking if it is called, so no need to wait for anything.

```
it('should initialize service and return res', () => {
    const mockService = sinon.stub(Service, 'initialize')
    mockService.withArgs({scope: 'param'}).returns(Promise.resolve(true))

    getResult()

    expect(mockService.callCount).to.equal(1)
  })
```

Comment: I don't know why but the following doesn't work:
const mockService = sinon.stub(Service, 'initialize')
mockService.withArgs({scope: 'param'}).returns({
      'success': () => {
        return true
      },
      'error': function () {}
    })
getResult()
expect(mockService.callCount).to.equal(1)

Comment: Ah, maybe because you are calling `const service = Service(config)` and it is overwriting your stub?

Comment: IDK, I even tried passing in the same config while creating the stub but that didn't work either. Shouldn't the stub be applied to the property `initialize` of the `Service` by default?